# Is $H^2$ weakly closed in $H$? Isaacs Finite Group Theory, exercise 8B.6

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to solve exercise 8B.6 on [page 249](http://books.google.com/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&pg=PA249) of Isaacs's *Finite Group Theory* textbook (the second question in a series; [this is the third as question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74386/primitive-permutation-group-with-subdegree-3)).  I have an idea, but it doesn't quite work.  It seems like the precursor to the idea in the next exercise, so I'd really like for it to work.

> **Can my idea be fixed?**

The exercise asks:

> If $G$ is a finite primitive permutation group with a point stabilizer $H$ that has an orbit of size 2, then $G$ is dihedral of order twice an odd prime in its natural action.

The previous exercise had the stabilizer's orbit size reduced to 1, and it followed by showing a maximal subgroup contained in two point stabilizers had to be the identity (which caused a huge collapse: $G$ is then cyclic of prime order).  Ok, so I want to do the same thing, $H$ has a big subgroup contained in two stabilizers, so that big subgroup is the identity (which finishes the whole thing for my choice of subgroup).

Here was the smaller question I had while doing that, but I answered it depressingly as: "No."

> Suppose $H$ is a maximal subgroup of the finite group $G$, and let $K = H^2 = E^2(H)$ be the subgroup of $H$ generated by the squares of the elements in $H$.  If $g\in G$ takes $K$ to $K^g ≤ H$, then must $g$ normalize $K$?

Well, taking $G$ to be $\operatorname{PGL}(2,q)$ for $q ≡ ±3\bmod 8$, and $H$ to be a Sylow 2-subgroup (so a dihedral group of order 8 with partial fusion), then $K$ is the order 2 normal subgroup of $H$ and is not weakly closed: there is a $g\in G$ that takes $K$ to a non-normal subgroup of order 2 in $H$.  When $q = 3$, $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G ≅ S_4$.

Now the action of $G$ on the cosets of $P$ is primitive, but not faithful, so this isn't actually a counterexample, but wow it seems close.

> Is it true that $K$ is weakly closed in $H$ (with respect to $G$) if $H$ is core-free (with respect to $G$)?

The only reason $H$ had a core was because $q$ was chosen so small.  But all $q$ have the same basic setup as far as the relationship of $K$ in $H$ and conjugation in $G$, it is just that $H$ is no longer maximal for larger $q$.

Comment: If the action of $G$ on the cosets of $P$ is primitive and faithful, then this is true, as $K$ is weakly closed in $P$ iff $K$ is normal in $N_G(P)$ (which is either $P$ or $G$ in this case).

Comment: I would also like to say +1!, because when I (finally) worked these three exercises out, there seemed to be no underlying, unifying idea behind my ad-hoc techniques.

Comment: Isn't this similar to the one with orbit size 3? Let $H=G_{\alpha,\beta}$. Then $|G_\alpha:H|=2$, hence also $|G_\beta:H|=2$, so $N_G(H)$ strictly contains $G_\alpha$, hence $H \lhd G$ and so $H=1$ and $|G_\alpha|=2$.

Comment: @SteveD: I think it is not true that K is weakly closed in P iff K is normal in N_G(P). For instance, when G=PGL(2,q) [q=±3 mod 8], Z(P) is normal in N_G(P), but there is a G-conjugate of Z(P) that is not normal in P. (exercise 5C.6 is strangely worded).

Comment: @Derek: Thanks.  I was trying to use an element that took a to b to be my extra member of the normalizer.  Just using G_b is a much better idea.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Yes, you're right, I was thinking the specific case $K=P^2$ would satisfy the last part of 5C.6b, but your example shows it doesn't.