# Primitive permutation group with subdegree 4

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> What are the possible sizes of a point stabilizer in a primitive permutation group, where the point stabilizer has an orbit of size 4?

In the tradition of [subdegree 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74386/primitive-permutation-group-with-subdegree-3) and [subdegree 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74626/is-h2-weakly-closed-in-h-isaacs-fgt-exercise-8b-6), I wonder about subdegree 4.  This would be the next exercise in the series 8B.5, 8B.6, 8B.7 on [page 249](http://books.google.com/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&pg=PA249) of Isaacs's Finite Group Theory textbook.

I have a rough proof that the point stabilizer has order of the form 2<sup>*a*</sup>3<sup>*b*</sup>, and (so far at least) all the examples I've looked at have *a* ≤ 5, *b* ≤ 2.

> Is it true that the point stabilizer has order of the form 2<sup>*a*</sup>3<sup>*b*</sup>?  If so, is it true that *a* ≤ 5, *b* ≤ 2?

In general, I think it is true that every prime divisor of the order of the point stabilizer is less than or equal to the size of the suborbit, but I don't have any real feel for how large the prime powers can be.  My proof is silly-easy and doesn't use any graph theory.

I haven't yet had a chance to carefully read Sims (1967) <sup>[exact *a* for subdegree 3]</sup>, Wong (1967) <sup>[exact structure for subdegree 3]</sup>, Sims (1968) <sup>[exact *a* for subdegree 4, but assuming *b*=0?]</sup>, Thompson (1970) <sup>[general control]</sup>, or Cameron et al. (1983) <sup>[existence of general bound]</sup>, so the answer could be fairly easy.

I think CPSS (1983) radically simplifies (maybe even trivializes) for subdegree 4, but Sims (1968) seems like only a partial answer.  It's not clear to me if we know some simple (at least for subdegree 4) combinatorics problem equivalent to this problem.

- Sims, Charles C.
  "Graphs and finite permutation groups."
  Math. Z. 95 (1967) 76–86.
  MR[204509](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=204509)
  DOI:[10.1007/BF01117534](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01117534)
- Wong, Warren J.
  "Determination of a class of primitive permutation groups."
  Math. Z. 99 (1967) 235–246.
  MR[214653](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=214653)
  DOI:[10.1007/BF01112454](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01112454)
- Sims, Charles C.
  "Graphs and finite permutation groups. II."
  Math. Z. 103 (1968) 276–281.
  MR[225865](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=225865)
  DOI:[10.1007/BF01114994](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01114994)
- Thompson, John G.
  "Bounds for orders of maximal subgroups."
  J. Algebra 14 (1970) 135–138.
  MR[252500](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=252500)
  DOI:[10.1016/0021-8693(70)90117-1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(70)90117-1)
- Cameron, P. J., Praeger, C. E., Saxl, J., & Seitz, G. M.
  "On the Sims conjecture and distance transitive graphs."
  Bull. London Math. Soc., 15(5) (1983) 499–506.
  MR[705530](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=705530) DOI:[10.1112/blms/15.5.499](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/blms/15.5.499)

Comment: I just had a quick look at the papers. Sims [1967], Theorem 5.4 gets a bound for the case when $G_\alpha$ induces $A_4$ on the orbit, and Sims [1967] does it when the induced action is a 2-group. That appears to leave the case when the induces action is $S_4$ - on the other hand, Thompson [1970] states that Sims got a bound in all cases in these two papers, so I don't know!

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring CPSS, which I am not sure is helpful to find the exact upper bound, the next important references on this problem are (in chronological order) :

[1] W.L. Quirin, Primitive permutation groups with small orbitals, Math. Z. 122 (1971) 267–274.

[2] J. Wang, The primitive permutation groups with an orbital of length 4, Comm. Algebra 20 (1992) 889–921.

[3] C.H. Li, Z.P. Lu, D. Marusic, On primitive permutation groups with small suborbits and their orbital graphs, J. Algebra 279 (2004) 749-770.

The best is simply to read the introduction to [3]. It includes a short history and the full list of possible stabilisers is given, including a correction about the claimed existence of an example of order $2^43^6$.

It turns out that the order of a stabiliser divides either $2^5$ or $2^43^2$ and this is sharp. (So the answer to your question is "yes".)